# Why are some cheeses not kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

Why are certain cheeses not kosher and some are kosher?

From the ingredients on the label it contains no non-kosher products or ingredients in it.

Comment: "From the indigents on the label it contains no non-kosher products or indigents in it" How do you know that?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63976/759

Comment: To distinguish from the possible duplicate DoubleAA linked to, I suggest revising this to ask what factors affect the kashrut of cheese.

Comment: Are you aware of the issues with rennet?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kosher-cheese/

Comment: http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/gevinas_yisroel_acid_cheese.php

Answer (score 4):

There are several Kosher concerns special to cheese that go beyond its ingredient list.

The biggest is the question of "[Gevinas Akum](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?cat=270&id=28062&q=)" (lit. cheese of a non-Jew). The Mishna says that cheese made by a non-Jew is forbidden, conceptually similar to wine. The exact parameters of this prohibition are debated, with opinions ranging from it is basically not operative (e.g. Rabbeinu Tam, mentioned in the Ramo in Shulchan Aruch to justify those who are lenient) to it applies to any and all forms of cheese (e.g. [Aruch HaShulchan](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kosher-cheese/)).

There are two general categories of cheese that are of Halachic significance. One is hard cheese, which requires rennet or something taking the place of rennet to make it. Then you have soft cheese which is called "acid set" because it is made by lactic acid fermenting in the milk.

The [generally accepted practice](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kosher-cheese/) of Kashrus agencies in America, at least, is to say that cheese that *requires* rennet - that means it could not be made with the acid set method, whatever the source and kosher status of the rennet used, requires the specific stringencies to avoid Gevinas Akum. The primary one (in terms of cost and therefore availability of Kosher product) is the presence of a supervising Mashgiach who inserts the Rennet or is at least present when it is inserted.

It should be noted that soft cheeses that are exempt from this often include rennet to rush the process, but since it would happen without the rennet, they are lenient.

Besides this, looking at the ingredient panel doesn't tell you about the Kosher status of the rennet or enzymes used (nor do they even list rennet with the name rennet, it can often be called enzyme, as that is what is interesting about rennet), so you could get the impression that it is fine without realizing it. Although animal based rennet is more expensive, it is still sometimes preferred by the manufacturer.

So the ingredients look Kosher, but are not.

Besides this you have intermingling issues. I know of a community where the Rabbi mistakenly certified cheese without realizing that it was immersed in the same salt bath (this is called brined cheese, at it can apply to cheeses that some are claiming are [soft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brined_cheese) as well as hard cheese, but more commonly hard) as the non-Kosher cheese. The psak was that anyone who cooked with the cheese had to Kasher their dishes. (I subsequently spoke to a Rabbi with deep knowledge and experience in the area and he said it is an understandable mistake to make, given how cheese production is set up and presented).

So there is a lot more to the Kashrus of cheese than its ingredients, and the ingredients themselves can be deceptive.

Comment: It is also worth noting that many cheeses state "non animal kosher rennet" as part of the ingredients on the packaging so that way one is sure all the ingredients are kosher. And they do this on non hecshered cheeses as well. Because otherwise you've scared people to not trusting food labels and therefore leaving them unaware that there are plenty of unhecshered cheeses that are completely kosher and permissible to eat

Comment: @Aaron He's encouraged people to only consider trusting labels if they know what they are talking about in terms of modern ingredient sourcing and production techniques. That's a good thing. Too many people have no idea what words on packages mean and claim to be able to tell if they are kosher because it doesn't say "pork" or "beef" or the like.

Comment: am learning and am new to a torah lifestyle...where come from things are labeled kosher and halal at the same time(expect meat products) ,,, i seen this only on one cheese product the rest types of cheeses are not marked kosher ...." cheese of a non-Jew" how can this be halal and kosher ?

Comment: http://www.clover.co.za/media/shared/downloadable/certificates/kosher_2016/Kosher_Clover_Lichtenburg_2016.pdf     http://www.clover.co.za/media/shared/downloadable/certificates/halaal_2016/Halaal_Clover_Lichtenburg_2016.jpg  above are to diffrent certifications for the same products ....am pretty sure these are   prepaid by non jews

Comment: @wesley7, I can't speak to Halal, but something being Halal won't stop it from being Kosher. "Cheese of a non-Jew" has specific Halachic remedies to prevent it from being a problem. If doing those don't interfere with Halal, then there is no reason it can't be both. Actually some muslims around my area will eat a product if it is Kosher, using that as a proxy to ensure the product meets Halal standards.

Comment: The Mishna says that cheese made by a non-Jew is forbidden...........so even its halal or kosher ...am 95% sure these a made by non jews here

Comment: @wesley7, it says "cheese *of* a non-Jew" not cheese *made by*. The ways to make it Kosher include: Being present at the insertion of the rennet (the most minimal standard), actually inserting the rennet, owning the rennet and owning the milk. Those last two can even be accomplished with pro-forma contracts similar to the inverse of Mechiras Chametz.

Comment: @andrew according to the accepted view, yes. The Talmud gives several possibilities.

Comment: @Aaron that's simply false. There is no cheese without hashgacha that is muter to for a Jew to consume.

Comment: @Dude Rabbeinu Tam (ibid.) asserts that the concerns are not relevant today, since snakes are not prevalent in our environs. He argues that Chazal did not issue this enactment in a situation where concern for snake venom is not relevant. Furthermore, he states: 
In many places, Jews eat cheese produced by non-Jews, since the non-Jews use flowers to curdle the milk, and the great rabbis of Narbonne (Southern France) permitted this practice. However, in our locales (Northern France and Germany) there is reason to be strict, since they use stomach linings to curdle milk.

Comment: @Dude I'll never be as great as Rabbeinu Tam, but he sure seem convinced that as long as you know ingredients and process you can rely on the leniency to eat cheese.  And I know for a fact that America does not allow snakes near milk or cheese, and that any manufacturer who claimed to use a kosher rennet and didn't would face a large lawsuit. I also know that no company is going to mix non kosher milk into the kosher milk because non kosher milk cannot curdle.

Comment: @Aaron that isn't the halacha, kosher is a religious belief so this is false, and today non kosher milk can be made into cheese. It's been done lots of times.

Comment: @Dude and how many times has non kosher milk been mixed into kosher milk in the US? Or any reputable cheese company in the modern era?

Comment: @Aaron I don't have that statistic. Regardless it doesn't change your statement to bring correct.

Comment: @Dude I'm not asking for statistics. I'm asking if you can find a single instance of it happening.

Comment: @aaron, "any manufacturer who claimed to use a kosher rennet and didn't would face a large lawsuit". That just isn't true. But please take this to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Hard cheeses are under similar strictures as wine.  Wine made in normal fashion is inherently kasher, however the Rabbis imposed an extra stringency that wine that was touched by a gentile becomes forbidden. The Rabbis noted that all soft rennet-less cheeses can only be made by milk from animal species that are kasher.  However, hard cheeses, cheeses that require rennet (historically part of an animals stomach) were problematic. The extra stringency against hard cheeses is under the category of givenat/gevinas akum.

So the ruling brought down by the Rabbis is that all soft rennet-less cheeses are automatically kasher.  This encompasses cream cheese, mozzarella, ricotta, Greek yogurts, labneh, feta etc etc.  This is why you will notice that most cream cheeses or other soft similar cheeses all have a hecsher, because kashrut agencies can certify the cheese without having to be present. This is also why you'll see Greek or middle eastern yogurts, even of the cheapest varities, also have hecshers. Heck, even the supermarket by my house has cheap imported Mexican Melting cheeses with hecshers, because the soft cheeses don't require supervision, so it's easy for companies to get hashgacha for all soft cheeses. So in reality there is usually no difference between hecshered or unhecshered soft cheeses, as they are (typically) both equally unsupervised. Even the OU admits this is common practice for hashgacha companies:

> Common practice (adopted by many kashrus agencies, based on the rationale in Igros Moshe YD 2 s. 45 and approved by Rav Yosef Eliyohu Henkin) is to follow the opinion that that the gezerah of gevinas akum was only declared on hard cheese, as only hard cheese uses rennet to form into curd and was therefore subject to the prohibition. Soft cheese, such as cream cheese and cottage cheese – also called “acid-set cheese” – does not need rennet to coagulate, as it can acidify and form on its own, and such cheese is therefore not subject to the rule of gevinas akum.

Source: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/kosher-cheese/

Another person posted here that you can't always "be sure" that the ingredients are kasher. This is sometimes true. However, MANY cheese companies go out of their way to put "non animal kosher rennet" in the ingredients list so that way you know for sure the product is kasher, even without a hecsher. You can rely on such ingredient lists. Here is an example of non hecshered feta that is completely kasher to eat according to Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi, and lists non animal kosher rennet as part of its ingredients:

[image: DOUBLE CREAM MYKONOS FETA. Ingredients: Cultured pasteurized Grade A whole milk, cream, calcium, salt, non-animal Kosher rennet. Contains: Milk.]

However, hard cheeses require direct supervision by a Jew, as their was concern of rennet coming from non kasher sources being used to make the hard cheese.  These types of cheeses are cheddar, permesian, or any cheese that typically appears as a solid block.

You can find more information about this through the very helpful website http://www.kashrut.org.
The website was brought into being by the renowned posek Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi to help simplify kashrut matters/questions.

For sources regarding the lack of supervision, people have reached out to the OK and OU and the responses they received were that neither the OU nor the OK supervises cream cheese, and i see no reason why this wouldn't apply to other soft cheeses.

> Kraft Philadelphia Cream Cheese is "supervised" by the OK and not the OU.
> The OK has a section on their website which indicates whether or not a Mashgiah is present for the "cheesing". These products as well as several types of Ricotta and Cottages cheeses that are "supervised" by the OK do NOT indicate that a Mashgiah is present for the production.

Source: [http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=6773](https://web.archive.org/web/20041128102442/https://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp/?mid=6773)

> I asked Rabbi Cohen if he would eat TempTee cream cheese he gave me what at first I considered an acceptable answer. He claimed that he only eats Chalav Yisrael and therefore, no he would not eat the brand even though it is OU. When I then asked him if I took Chalav Yisrael to the TempTee factory and told them to use this milk in a batch of cream cheese, making it the
> same way and watching it the same way as is presently done, would he eat it? he asked for some time to think about it. After a week I called back for the answer and he told me he hadn't
> thought about it but that it would be wiser if I shared my concerns
> with you. I pose the same question to you. If you tell me that the OU
> doesn't consider cream cheese cheese, then how many of the mashgihim
> or rabbis working for the OU would eat unsupervised cream cheese? If
> the majority  would not eat it then where is the Union in Orthodox
> Union?? I have heard many times in my life that the kashrus business
> is just that... a business, but never fully believed it before. The OU
> has a chance to prove that it has not become merely a business. As far
> as I am concerned, if the Rabbis of the OU would not eat cream cheese
> because of gevinat acum then they have truly transgressed the law of
> not putting a stumbling block before a blind person!

Source: [http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=6773](https://web.archive.org/web/20041128102442/https://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp/?mid=6773)

Comment: "The website was created by the renowned posek Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi" I'm fairly certain it's his sons, not him, who created the website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44763/discussion-between-aaron-and-double-aa) (discussion between Aaron and DoubleAA).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation among Aaron, Yishai, and SethJ has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44764/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-why-are-some-cheeses-not-kosher).

Comment: Aaron, looking at your latest edit, I think you may misunderstand what kashrut.org does. He investigates those products he says are fine (e.g. http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=62044&highlight=), but rarely tells you want it took, what question he asked the company, what they answered. If you understand from him saying product X with an ingredient label is fine doesn't mean he would say the same from another manufacturer. He may well have called the company to find out what other cheeses they manufacture to see if the brine is a problem for the feta, for example.

Comment: @Yisha "In answer to a cheese question by Giovanna, you state that feta cheese is a soft cheese and does not need a hechsher. Are you saying, therefore, that ALL brands of feta cheese are kosher?
Please clarify." Response from Rabbi Abadi's Son: Yes. If the ingredients listed are good.  Source: http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=52097&highlight=feta

Comment: @Aaron, first three letters is all that's needed. I searched his Q&A, I have no idea if he is aware of the brine issue.

Comment: @Yishai I would be thoroughly impressed if he was not aware of the issue.  This website has been up for years, with many people arguing against him.  Why don't you ask him if brine is an issue? Either way, i don't think I've misunderstood him. Do you think I have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44799/discussion-between-yishai-and-aaron).

Comment: That last block quote in your answer really doesn't belong. The letter writer is claiming that cream cheese (Kal Vechomer Feta, Mozzerrella, etc.) always needs to be Gevinas Yisroel and the OU is being hypocritical by allowing it, ostensibly for business reasons. I think that is completely unfair to the OU, et. al., but that is a separate point. It completely undermines your answer.